# Centering items in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I'm using a few LinearLayouts and am having trouble getting the items to be centered.

Here's my code block:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/avatar"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:background="@drawable/touch_clear_bg" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/subtitle"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:visibility="gone"/>
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

So I want the `ImageView` and the `nested LinearLayout` to be **vertically centered** in the `title_container`, which is a horizontal `LinearLayout`.

Is there a reason why my approach isn't working?

Comment: try replacing layout_gravity with gravity in nested LinearLayout params

Comment: add layout_gravity="center" at the Root Linear Layout

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the 
 `android:gravity="center_vertical"`
only in the parent LinearLayout(title_container).

And you can see the code here:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/title_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/avatar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />  

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/touch_clear_bg" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

**change**

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

**to**

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 0):

Type

`<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center">`

This will put whole layout in center